# SQL Stored Procedure execution time difference

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have strange issue in my win-form application where I am calling a stored procedure and it takes about 6 seconds to execute.
(This stored procedure accepts several parameters including one output parameter)

From application level I used :

```
Dim dt1 = DateTime.Now
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt1).Seconds)
```

This is about 5-6 seconds

I have tried running the same stored procedure with same parameters on `sql-server` and it takes no time to execute:

```
declare @val decimal
exec mysp 'value1','value2','value3','value4',@val out 
select @val
```

I am not sure what the issue is or where to start.

Comment: Is there any other code happening before the actual stored procedure call in your code? How did you measure the 6 seconds?

Comment: @KarlAnderson: I have updated the question with the application level code block where I capture the time

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler to see if it is executing the same SQL as you think it is?

Comment: @KarlAnderson: It gave me index suggestions which I created

Answer (score 1):

The issue with difference between calling SP directly and from .NET code, maybe due to parameter sniffing. SQL Server maybe caching execution plan that is not optimal for the parameters you're passing from code.

To avoid this try adding WITH RECOMPILE to your SP definition, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySP (
    ... parameters...
) WITH RECOMPILE

AS

BEGIN
   ...
```

Comment: I tried executing the sp like `exec mysp 'value1','value2','value3','value4',@val out with recompile` and seems it takes longer time than the application

Comment: Don't *execute* SP  with recompile. CREATE or ALTER SP with recompile.

Comment: Are u sure you're applying WITH RECOMPILE only as example above is showing and nowhere else? If anything you should not notice any significant slow downs.

Comment: Yes, I just alter the procedure with recomplile

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue if your stored procedure expects say nvarchar and you use a varchar. SQL server will accept the parameters but will be forced to do a conversion. Do you have more specifics?

Comment: All the parameter are `varchar, int,datetime` and `float` output

Comment: Try running SQL profiler against the two methods that should be able to tell you what is the difference between the two calls to yhe server.